# Pass the magento data to json

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, magento2.2, json

I need a small help. How to pass the values to json with different values.

```
$params =   array( 'OrderLineId'=>$orderLineId,
                            'MaterialNo'=>$materialNo,
                            'PlanType'=>$planType,
                            'Qty'=>$qty,
                            'UnitPrice'=>$unitPrice,
                            'UnitTax'=>$UnitTax,
                            'DiscountRate'=>$DiscountRate,
                            'Discount'=>$Discount);
$orderData = array('OrderId'=>$orderId,
                            'StoreId'=>$storeId,
                            'PartnerId'=>  $partnerId,
                            'CustomerId'=> $customerId,
                            'OrderType'=> $orderType,
                            'OrderSource'=>  $orderSource,
                            'CurrId'=> $currId,
                            'UserName'=> $userName);
```

I need to pass the values like

```
"OrderHeader": { "OrderId": "12", "StoreId": "main_website_store", "PartnerId": "15", "CustomerId": "16", "OrderType": "NEW", "OrderSource": "Megento", "CurrId": "USD", "UserName": "sdfdsfdsf" },
"OrderDetail": [ { "OrderLineId": "string", "MaterialNo": "79c29af7-3cd0-4a6f-b182-a81e31dec84e", "PlanType": "Anual","Qty": 0,"UnitPrice": 0.1, "UnitTax": 0.1,"DiscountRate": 0.1,"Discount": 0.1},{    "OrderLineId": "string", "MaterialNo": "BCESS876","PlanType": "Month","Qty": 2,"UnitPrice": 0.1,"UnitTax": 0.1,"DiscountRate": 0.1,"Discount": 0.1}]}
```

any one please help me.

Comment: This isn't really a magento question, but a PHP question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373315/is-there-a-way-to-pass-multiple-arrays-to-php-json-encode-and-parse-it-with-jque

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$data = array(
    'OrderHeader' => $orderData,
    'OrderDetail' => array(
        $params
    )
);
$json = json_encode($data);
```

Comment: once I get a success response from rest API then only place the order how to write the condition?